# Drivers for Nvidia GeForce GT 430?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently bought a Nvidia GeForceGT 430. When I boot into Ubuntu, it looks low quality. I think its because I don't have the device drivers. Does anyone know how to download the drivers?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Additional Drivers utility to see if it suggests anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in "drivers" from the unity launcher. Open "Install Additional Drivers" from the menu. You should see two options to install latest drivers created by NVidia and tested by the Ubuntu team. This should work, but note that since it is a proprietary driver, you may have some issues.

I would recommend launching `nvidia-settings` from the terminal and seeing if there are any obvious settings that you can tweak to get some better performance.

If you are still having trouble, you could download the drivers straight from the NVidia site:

x86 - http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-285.05.09-driver.html 
x64 - http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-285.05.09-driver.html

I would use installing from NVidia as a last step if you simple cannot get anything else working.

Best of luck!