# Can't drag window into workspace ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, workspaces, multiple-workstations

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 yesterday alongside Win 7 to try it out (and maybe get rid of Win). I liked the workspace concept a lot, dragging a window into another workspace form the four-workspaces-view. Then after some installing I had a crash - Ubuntu would not start any more and I hat do go through the Ubuntu setup from Windows again (three times until I got rid of the crash problem). But ever since the drag and drop function in the 4-workspace view does not work any more. I googled a lot, installed unity and compiz config, changed hundreds of settings but can't get it back. everything else (shift-alt arrow and right clicks on the menubar) work, but i can't click on the miniaturized windows in the workspace selector any more.

any idea?

Comment: Since you solved this by installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, you should post an answer saying you solved it in this way, and then (a day later, when you can), accept this answer. (Unless there is already another answer you believe is correct and works, which you are willing to accept.)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

OP Solved this by installing Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Unity 2D? I don't think you can move applications between workspaces in the Unity 2D view.

To see if you are running 2D:

1. Log out by clicking the cog wheel in the top right corner of your desktop and selecting "Log Out".
   You will be presented with the login screen.
2. Now click the little cog wheel next to the password input box and see if "Ubuntu 2d" is selected.

If "Ubuntu 2D" *is* selected, **DON'T** just select "Ubuntu" and log back in. If you find yourself unexpectedly in 2d it is probably because you aren't using the right driver for your graphics card.
To install a driver for your graphics card:

1. Open the Dash ( "windows" or "super key" on your keyboard)
2. Type "Drivers"
3. Select "Install Additional Drivers"
4. Find a driver for your graphics card and click "Activate"
5. Restart
6. Try loging in to 3d by hitting the cog wheel (at the login screen) and select "Ubuntu"

If you just get a frozen desktop, power off and log back into 2d and try another driver.
 (I had to try several times)

After you get a good driver you should be able to move windows between workspaces.

Hope This helped!

Sources:

[Drivers for Nvidia GeForce GT 430?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77312/drivers-for-nvidia-geforce-gt-430)

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/unity-2d-gets-workspace-switcher-too.html

Personal Experience

EDIT:  I think there is also a Unity 2d bug report on this (not sure).

Comment: strange is i could move them the first time i installed ubuntu, now i cant't get it back. i even changed drivers like you said even if it was always unity 3d. no change.

Comment: Can you add more detail the the question? What happens when you try  to move a window between workspaces? and what do you mean by " but i can't click on the miniaturized windows in the workspace selector any more."

Comment: in the workspace overview (four screen view) i believe i could grab a window (for ex. the chromium window) and drag it into the next screen. that's how i remember it worked the first time - but as i said ubuntu crashed and i reinstalled it three times via the wubi.exe from win7.now i can open the 4 screen view but can not click on the miniatuized programwindows any more. i can just select the screen  i wish to switch to.

Comment: Could you try making a screencast with some of the tools here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast I don't know if you want to go through all that though.

Comment: Ok, messed around with the system a couple of days. now i get the opengl version 2.1 Mesa 7.11 - Not software rendered: no - Not blacklisted: yes - blablabla: yes - Unity 3D supported: no.      So I tried the original NVIDIA-website drivers which gave me serious problems (no gui at all, only terminal) and some other solutions (have now xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, bumblebee optimus-support and some other files installed) but haven't got nearer to the solution. seems as if the optimus card is the culprit, so i'll monitor the bumblebee project for evolutions. thanks to all so far

Answer (score 0):

Form what I gathered from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106731/unity-2d-and-3d-both-running) question try running this command in the terminal:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

At the bottom of the output you get it should tell you if your computer supports Unity 3D.

Comment: my output is: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: unable to create the OpenGL context                          i have a new aspire 5750G i5-2410M 2.3 GHz with NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M and 4 GB Ram, should do the trick. Maybe a driver problem? Had them updated, though. I just don't know whether I had success...

Comment: No It doesn't look like you had success. Look at the first answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106731/unity-2d-and-3d-both-running) thats success (yours won't be exactly the same though)

Comment: How many drivers does it offer you when you try to install them? I had like three or four and only one worked when I went through this.

Comment: You could also download the drivers manually [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Comment: Ok, messed around with the system a couple of days. now i get the opengl version 2.1 Mesa 7.11 - Not software rendered: no - Not blacklisted: yes - blablabla: yes - Unity 3D supported: no.      So I tried the original NVIDIA-website drivers which gave me serious problems (no gui at all, only terminal) and some other solutions (have now xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, bumblebee optimus-support and some other files installed) but haven't got nearer to the solution. seems as if the optimus card is the culprit, so i'll monitor the bumblebee project for evolutions. thanks to all so far